# Radio button created as user control binding to observablecollection of enums

Tags: wpf

Have a user control created with radio button binding to a enum property.
Everything works when one user control is added to main window, but things go awkward when we have more than one user control all are bonded to same enum property. change one of them and all the radio buttons show same value.

How can i bind a radio button in a user control to observable collection of enum?
so that any number of user controls added to main window wil have independent binding.

ViewModel:

```
public enum SISOModels
    {
        NoModel,
        PredictionOnly,
        PredictionAndControl
    };

 private SISOModels _sisoModel;
        public SISOModels sisoModel
        { 
            get
            {
                return _sisoModel;
            }
            set
            {
                _sisoModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("sisoModel");
            }
        }

private ObservableCollection<SISOModels> _sisoModelList;
        public ObservableCollection<SISOModels> sisoModelList
        {
            get
            {
                return _sisoModelList;
            }
            set
            {
                _sisoModelList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("sisoModelList");
            }
        }
```

View:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="r1" Content="No Model" FontSize="16" IsChecked= "{Binding Path = sisoModel , Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.NoModel}}"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="r2" Content="Prediction Only" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path = sisoModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionOnly}}"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="r3" Content="Prediction And Control" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path = sisoModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionAndControl}}"/>
```

this works as i am binding to one enum property but with multiple such user controls added all are binded to same enum property.

if i change it to this:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="r1" Content="No Model" FontSize="16" IsChecked= "{Binding Path = sisoModelList , Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.NoModel}}"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="r2" Content="Prediction Only" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path = sisoModelList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionOnly}}"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="r3" Content="Prediction And Control" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path = sisoModelList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionAndControl}}"/>
```

i get error saying "binding should be a enum"

Comment: sounds like you aren't using the DataContext of the user control?

Comment: I am setting the datacontext to my view model. view model has observable collection property for enum. How do i bind this to my radio button? as radio button binding is only to enum and not to collection of enum

Comment: with just one enum property my binding looks like this:<RadioButton x:Name="r1" Content="No Model" FontSize="16" IsChecked= "{Binding Path = sisoModelList[1] , Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.NoModel}}"/>

Comment: now with observablecollection of enums how will i bind? if i give the observablecollection property name of binding it throws me an error "binding to be enum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You can use, for example, `ItemsControl`:

Assuming you have a view model:

```
enum Enumeration { One, Two, Three }

class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<Enumeration> { Enumeration.One, Enumeration.Three };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Enumeration> Collection { get; private set; }
}
```

Then add an `ItemsControl` container:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>    
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

You then set your collection as the items source, and your control would be the data template.
In my example, this control is a simple `TextBlock`, but you can use your custom control here.

**EDIT:**

There is no problem using converters, too. You just need to use the right `Path`. By the way, the `IsChecked` property binding is `TwoWay` by default, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.
You can replace the `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` or any container you like.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>    
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding sisoModelList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="r1" Content="No Model" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.NoModel}}"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="r2" Content="Prediction Only" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionOnly}}"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="r3" Content="Prediction And Control" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionAndControl}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: but for radio buttons we need converter as well. Can you check my code above?

Comment: Why do you want to bind your `RadioButton`s to an `ObservableCollection`, if you define all the controls explicitly in the view? What happens if the view model adds or removes items in that `ObservableCollection` (sisoModelList)?

Comment: reason for going with user control is that we only get to know the number of these radio button controls to be added in runtime. it may be 4*3 or 4*4 or 5*5. we do not have any control on this number. i use a grid and populate these user controls at runtime

Comment: May be i have confused a lot. My requirement is to have a grid which is dynamic (number of rows and columns will be known at run time) i need to add radio button user control created in all the cells and it should have data binding. i thought of using observablecollection of enums but not sure how to bind that to my user control

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: Have hit one more road block. After implementing this solution, i see now that twoway databinding to my enum collection is not working. First time binding works and it fetches the collection and updates all my radio buttons but subsequent changes of radio buttons are not reflecting to me view model.